# NodeJS Express POST Request

Tags: node.js, http-post

Having some slight difficulty with making a POST request to an API. The goal is to make a POST request and just print the response to console for now. This is basically what I have done, please let me know as to what I am doing wrong.

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var data = JSON.parse('{ "user": "username", "password": "pass", "layout": "out" }');
    console.log(data);

    request({
        url : "https://url.com",
        method : "POST",
        json: true,
        body : data
    }, function(error, response, body){
        console.log(body);
    });

    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

The issue i am facing is that while doing the same request using Postman as shown in this [image] is providing a response while if i print the response or body in Node, its shown as undefined.

Comment: can you mntin what is the problem you are facing exactly?

Comment: Basically, when i try to print the body or the response. Its shown as undefined while doing the exact same POST request through something like Postman provides me with a response.